# Try to finding suitable condition to show a mathematical expression.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, special-functions

Given, $f(x)$ is an increasing real valued function on $(0,1)$.

Also, $f(x)\gt 1$ on $(0,1)$.

Then, what condition one need to show for any $0<x<y<1$, $f(y)^x\lt f(x)^y$

I am totally blind here that what is the way to show it.

please help me with anything.

Answer (score 1):

You want $x \ln f(y)<y\ln f(x)$ or $\frac {\ln f(y)} y<\frac {\ln f(x)} x$ for $x<y$. This means $\frac {\ln f(x)} x$ is a decreasing function. To get a simple usable condition I will assume that $f$ is differentiable.

The derivative of this function is $(x\frac {f'(x)} {f(x)} -\ln f(x))/x^{2}$ so you need $x\frac {f'(x)} {f(x)} <
\ln f(x)$ or $f'(x)<\frac { f(x)\ln f(x)} x$. I hope this helps.

Comment: What if $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: Can you make the required condition based on rate of change of function $f(x)$ on (0,1)?

Comment: You are asking for too much. With just montonicoty you won't get any simple condition for the inequality to hold.  @Alearner

Comment: Rate of change of a function is precisely its derivative.  @Alearner

Comment: You can add that '"$f$ is continuous" as a necessary condition as well. If it were not then you got to furnish some more information about your $f$.

Comment: @vishalnaakar No, $f$ do not have to be continuous, see the comment in my answer.

Comment: There is a typo in the end: $\log x$ should be replaced by $\log f(x)$

Comment: @AD-StopPutin- Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the problem we can set $f(x) = e^{x h(x)}$.

Then $f(x)>1$ means $h(x)>0$ for $x\in (0,1)$.
Also, the condition that $f$ is increasing, means that $xh(x)$ is increasing.

For the final condition $0<x<y<1 \Rightarrow f(y)^x<f(x)^y$, note that
$$f(y)^x<f(x)^y \Longleftrightarrow f(y)^{1/y}<f(x)^{1/x} \Longleftrightarrow e^{yh(y)/y}<e^{xh(x)/x}=e^{h(y)}<e^{h(x)}$$
Which means that $h$ is a decreasing function.

A typical example of such a function $h$, is $h(x)= x^{-\alpha}$ where $\alpha\in(0,1)$.

---

Moreover, the function $h$ (and hence $f$) does not have to be continuous.

We can set
$h(x)= x^{-\alpha}$ for $0<x<1/2$, and
$h(x)= x^{-\beta}$ for $1/2\leq x<1$, provided $0<\beta<\alpha<1$.

(However, monotone functions are differentiable almost everywhere, and hence continuous ”almost everywhere” (a theorem of Lebesgue).
Which means that it can not be discontinuous in a ”thick” set.)